# How to disable Tempo Span Metrics when using OpenTelemetry Agent?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, open-telemetry, tempo

I use the OpenTelemetry JavaAgent to send traces directly to Tempo in Grafana Cloud. The OpenTelemetry JavaAgent is configured through environment variables.

This produces many span metrics (https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/metrics-generator/span_metrics/) in Prometheus:

```
- traces_spanmetrics_latency_bucket
- traces_spanmetrics_latency_count
- traces_spanmetrics_latency_sum
- traces_spanmetrics_calls_total
- traces_spanmetrics_size_total
```

Is there a way to disable the automatic metric generation with the OpenTelemetry Agent?

Comment: Your Tempo generates those metrics, so configure your Tempo properly.